# MVP vs MVC vs MVVM vs VIPER in iOS

Tags: ios, model-view-controller, mvvm, mvp, viper-architecture

Does there exist any sample Swift code (same project rewritten multiple times) which was written in all of the major architectures/designs, which would include: MVP, MVC, MVVM and/or MVVM-C, and VIPER. I am seeking complete quantitative performance usage about those design architectures, as well as qualitative comparison of the impact on the source code by those design architectures. I have already read many articles but all that I get from there is theory and definitions.

Comment: Have look this for full detail https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/ios-architecture-patterns-ecba4c38de52

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check https://github.com/tailec/ios-architecture
It has the same project written in required architecture patterns.